# Do you have a function (else than random) to find random dice(from 1 to 6) numbers(in C++)

Tags: c++, random

I am writing a code for a game with seven dices and I have a problem. If I use a random function(dice = rand()%6 + 1) I realized the probability to get for instance a sequence such as 123456 (a sequence that makes points in my game) has a much higher probability to get out.
Mathematically, this sequence has 1.54% probability to show up but When I use a random function with 100 millions iterations it appears up to 5.4% of the time!

That leads me to my question. Do you know another way I could randomize the dice so that they would respect the probability? Or a way to fix that problem anyway?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want to custom randomize it?

Comment: Yup, a bunch of stuff was thrown into the standard from C++ 11 and on, see the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) , if you want to roughly match the "mathematical" probability have a look at `std::uniform_int_distribution`

Comment: `rand()` isn't that bad on any recent implementation.

Comment: The problem he is facing will occur even if an implementation of `rand()` is able to distribute uniformly since it is based on the usage of module together with `rand()`

Comment: Pretend for a moment that `rand()` returns values uniformly distributed in the closed range [0, 6]. When you get values from 0 to 5, `rand() % 6` gives you values from 0 to 5. when `rand()` returns 6, `rand() % 6` gives you 0. So you'll get 0 twice as often as any other value. That's the problem with using the remainder operator (`%` is **not** modulus, although many people call it that) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is well known and a very natural result of using the modulo operator with random.

C++11 solves these problems by providing not only uniformly distributed random numbers but several different types of distributions like the [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution), the [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) and the [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution).

The new header providing all these generators and distributions is [random](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/).

Let's do an example: We want do have a random number generator that gives us some numbers and we want to have a distribution that shapes these numbers as we want them (uniformly, Bernoulli ...).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main(){
    std::mt19937(6473);    // The random number generator using a deterministic seed
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1,6);    // The distribution that gives us random numbers in [1, 6)

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        std::cout << dist(mt) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

This gives us pseudo-random numbers **uniformly distributed** into an interval we chose! But C++11 provides even more! It provides a real random number generator (see implementations for more details) which we can use as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main(){
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());    // The random number generator using a non-deterministic random device
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(1,6);    // The distribution that gives us random numbers in [1,6)

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        std::cout << dist(mt) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

It is this easy to provide real high quality random numbers distributed as you want into and interval you want using C++11. I got the knowlege about this topic from a talk of Stephen T. Lavavej (STL) held at *GoingNative 2013* that you can watch on [Channel 9](https://channel9.msdn.com/) and that is called [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).

*Fun fact:* The title is a reference to an essay from the great [Edsger Wybe Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_W._Dijkstra) called "Go to considered harmful." in which Dijkstra explained why no programmer should use the goto statement.

Answer (score -1):

If you want some good random numbers using the boost library random function is a good place to start. Also has the example of working with dice like you are asking. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_random.html